# Statistical MODE function in Teradata SQL or SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, mode

Does anyone know if there is a Statistical MODE function (most frequent observation) in Teradata SQL or SAS SQL? Or any alternative to create the table below:

I want to create a table with a group variable, distinct count, mean and mode, something like this:

```
Select a, Count(Distinct(b)), Avg(c), *Mode*(c)
From table
Group By a;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any particular preference if a dataset has multiple modes?

Comment: I just tried to write a custom `mode()` function using proc fcmp.  For reasons too long to list here, I'm pretty sure it's impossible unless you insert certain flags into your dataset prior to running the SQL statement.

Answer (score 4):

There is no function for MODE calculation in SAS. you would need to use PROC MEANS or SUMMARY or UNIVARIATE to calculate the MODE or you could code a datastep to get it. CLASS statement can have your group by variable.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class MODE;
class sex;
run;
```

Again, for teradata as well there is no function to calculate MODE. You would need to code SQL to get the MODE. I have learned this from **Dieter** some time back

```
SELECT column
FROM table
GROUP BY column
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) = 1
```

Comment: no, the above mentioned SQL is for Teradata and not for SAS.

Comment: Hi sushil, would you be able to expand this query a bit so that it will find the MODE for each group "a", as in my original query. This QUALIFY RANK() is quite new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this in SAS SQL.  Simply get counts for the variable you want to calculate the mode of:

```
proc sql noprint ;
  create table tmp as
  select age, count(*) as freq
  from sashelp.class
  group by age
  order by freq desc
  ;
quit;
```

The above statement will return the count for all unique values, but we only want the most common. Because we are sorting the output in descending order, we can add `outobs=1` to the `proc sql` statement to it like so to just return the first result:

```
proc sql noprint outobs=1;
```

If you want to save the value to a macro variable, instead of creating a table, it would become:

```
proc sql noprint outobs=1;      
  select age, count(*) into :mode, :count
  from sashelp.class
  group by age
  order by 2 desc
  ;
quit;

%put &mode;
```

Comment: I guess technically this isn't the same as having a `mode()` function.

Comment: I'd also recommend the `proc means` approach that @sushil responded with.  My answer is more just for the sake of doing it with an SQL approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your input. It seems to me there is not a neater way to find all those statistics in a single proc or sql. One thing I found is to use PROC REPORT:

```
Proc Report Data=SASHelp.Class NoWd;
Column Sex N Age=Mean_Age Age=Mode_Age;
Define Sex / Group;
Define Mean_Age / Analysis Mean;
Define Mode_Age / Analysis Mode;
Run;
```

The only problem with this is unable to find unique/distinct count.